# How to adjust Windows "Visual Effects" option?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

What is the system call to adjust the "Visual Effects" settings in Windows Vista or 7?

Specifically, I want to adjust it from "Adjust for best appearance" to "Adjust for best performance".

My first thought was to use [SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETUIEFFECTS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx), but that appears to do nothing when called.

This is the dialog Windows provides to make the change manually:

[alt text http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6615/adjust.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6615/adjust.png)